# How to get notified when the internet connectivity is available when the application is in background without using broadcast receivers

Tags: android, networking, service, android-connectivitymanager

I have an application in which need to do some operation when internet is available even if app is in background or not available in the recent list.
I do not want to use broadcast receivers.

How can I achieve this.?

Comment: `I do not want to use broadcast receivers.` why not ? it becomes a lot harder to achieve a goal when you just exclude certain technologies

Comment: Well internet connection state broadcast is not usable for background apps anways. Have you looked at `WorkManager` ?